# I have a flatlist in react Native but i press button save not reload data automatically

Tags: android, ios, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have a flatlist in react Native  but i press button save not reload data automatically and not render in flattest but i reload app and the item save appears

I need that I press button save the data render data automatically in a flatList I need help

List screen:

```
class ListScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(Props);

    this.state = {
      listData : [ ]
    };

  }

  render() { return (

    <Root>
      <View style={styles.listScreenContainer}>
        <CustomButton
          text="Add Restaurant"
          width="94%"
          onPress={ () => { this.props.navigation.navigate("AddScreen"); } }
        />
        <FlatList
          style={styles.restaurantList}
          data={this.state.listData}
          renderItem={ ({item}) =>
            <View style={styles.restaurantContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.restaurantName}>{item.name}</Text>
              <CustomButton
                text="Delete"
                onPress={ () => {
                  Alert.alert(
                    "Please confirm",
                    "Are you sure you want to delete this restaurant?",
                    [
                      { text : "Yes", onPress: () => {
                        // Pull data out of storage.
                        AsyncStorage.getItem("restaurants",
                          function(inError, inRestaurants) {
                            if (inRestaurants === null) {
                              inRestaurants = [ ];
                            } else {
                              inRestaurants = JSON.parse(inRestaurants);
                            }
                            // Find the right one to delete and splice it out.
                            for (let i = 0; i < inRestaurants.length; i++) {
                              const restaurant = inRestaurants[i];
                              if (restaurant.key === item.key) {
                                inRestaurants.splice(i, 1);
                                break;
                              }
                            }
                            // Store updated data in storage.
                            AsyncStorage.setItem("restaurants",
                              JSON.stringify(inRestaurants), function() {
                                // Set new state to update list.
                                this.setState({ listData : inRestaurants });
                                // Show toast message to confirm deletion.
                                Toast.show({
                                  text : "Restaurant deleted",
                                  position : "bottom",
                                  type : "danger",
                                  duration : 2000
                                });
                              }.bind(this)
                            );
                          }.bind(this)
                        );
                      } },
                      { text : "No" },
                      { text : "Cancel", style : "cancel" }
                    ],
                    { cancelable : true }
                  )
              } } />
            </View>
          }
        />
      </View>
    </Root>

  ); }

  componentDidMount() {

    // Block hardware back button on Android.
    BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress", () => { return true; }
    );

    // Get list of restaurants.
    AsyncStorage.getItem("restaurants",
      function(inError, inRestaurants) {
        if (inRestaurants === null) {
          inRestaurants = [ ];
        } else {
          inRestaurants = JSON.parse(inRestaurants);
        }
        this.setState({ listData : inRestaurants });
      }.bind(this)
    );

  };


}
```

Add screen:

```js
class AddScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name : "",
      cuisine : "",
      price : "",
      rating : "",
      phone : "",
      address : "",
      webSite : "",
      delivery : "",
      key : `r_${new Date().getTime()}`
    };

  }

  render() { return (

    <ScrollView style={styles.addScreenContainer}>
      <View style={styles.addScreenInnerContainer}>
        <View style={styles.addScreenFormContainer}>
          <CustomTextInput
            label="Name"
            maxLength={20}
            stateHolder={this}
            stateFieldName="name"
          />
          <Text style={styles.fieldLabel}>Cuisine</Text>
          <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
            <Picker
              style={styles.picker}
              prompt="Cuisine"
              selectedValue={this.state.cuisine}
              onValueChange={
                (inItemValue) => this.setState({ cuisine : inItemValue })
              }
            >
              <Picker.Item label="" value="" />
              <Picker.Item label="Algerian" value="Algerian" />
              <Picker.Item label="American" value="American" />
              <Picker.Item label="BBQ" value="BBQ" />
              <Picker.Item label="Belgian" value="Belgian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Brazilian" value="Brazilian" />
              <Picker.Item label="British" value="British" />
              <Picker.Item label="Cajun" value="Cajun" />
              <Picker.Item label="Canadian" value="Canadian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Chinese" value="Chinese" />
              <Picker.Item label="Cuban" value="Cuban" />
              <Picker.Item label="Egyptian" value="Egyptian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Filipino" value="Filipino" />
              <Picker.Item label="French" value="French" />
              <Picker.Item label="German" value="German" />
              <Picker.Item label="Greek" value="Greek" />
              <Picker.Item label="Haitian" value="Haitian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Hawaiian" value="Hawaiian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Indian" value="Indian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Irish" value="Irish" />
              <Picker.Item label="Italian" value="Italian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Japanese" value="Japanese" />
              <Picker.Item label="Jewish" value="Jewish" />
              <Picker.Item label="Kenyan" value="Kenyan" />
              <Picker.Item label="Korean" value="Korean" />
              <Picker.Item label="Latvian" value="Latvian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Libyan" value="Libyan" />
              <Picker.Item label="Mediterranean" value="Mediterranean" />
              <Picker.Item label="Mexican" value="Mexican" />
              <Picker.Item label="Mormon" value="Mormon" />
              <Picker.Item label="Nigerian" value="Nigerian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Other" value="Other" />
              <Picker.Item label="Peruvian" value="Peruvian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Polish" value="Polish" />
              <Picker.Item label="Portuguese" value="Portuguese" />
              <Picker.Item label="Russian" value="Russian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Salvadorian" value="Salvadorian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Sandwiche Shop" value="Sandwiche Shop" />
              <Picker.Item label="Scottish" value="Scottish" />
              <Picker.Item label="Seafood" value="Seafood" />
              <Picker.Item label="Spanish" value="Spanish" />
              <Picker.Item label="Steak House" value="Steak House" />
              <Picker.Item label="Sushi" value="Sushi" />
              <Picker.Item label="Swedish" value="Swedish" />
              <Picker.Item label="Tahitian" value="Tahitian" />
              <Picker.Item label="Thai" value="Thai" />
              <Picker.Item label="Tibetan" value="Tibetan" />
              <Picker.Item label="Turkish" value="Turkish" />
              <Picker.Item label="Welsh" value="Welsh" />
            </Picker>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.fieldLabel}>Price</Text>
          <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
            <Picker
              style={styles.picker}
              selectedValue={this.state.price}
              prompt="Price"
              onValueChange={
                (inItemValue) => this.setState({ price : inItemValue })
              }
            >
              <Picker.Item label="" value="" />
              <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
              <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
              <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
              <Picker.Item label="4" value="4" />
              <Picker.Item label="5" value="5" />
            </Picker>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.fieldLabel}>Rating</Text>
          <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
            <Picker
              style={styles.picker}
              selectedValue={this.state.rating}
              prompt="Rating"
              onValueChange={
                (inItemValue) => this.setState({ rating : inItemValue })
              }
            >
              <Picker.Item label="" value="" />
              <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
              <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
              <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
              <Picker.Item label="4" value="4" />
              <Picker.Item label="5" value="5" />
            </Picker>
          </View>
          <CustomTextInput
            label="Phone Number"
            maxLength={20}
            stateHolder={this}
            stateFieldName="phone"
          />
          <CustomTextInput
            label="Address"
            maxLength={20}
            stateHolder={this}
            stateFieldName="address"
          />
          <CustomTextInput
            label="Web Site"
            maxLength={20}
            stateHolder={this}
            stateFieldName="webSite"
          />
          <Text style={styles.fieldLabel}>Delivery?</Text>
          <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
            <Picker
              style={styles.picker}
              prompt="Delivery?"
              selectedValue={this.state.delivery}
              onValueChange={
                (inItemValue) => this.setState({ delivery : inItemValue })
              }
            >
              <Picker.Item label="" value="" />
              <Picker.Item label="Yes" value="Yes" />
              <Picker.Item label="No" value="No" />
            </Picker>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.addScreenButtonsContainer}>
          <CustomButton
            text="Cancel"
            width="44%"
            onPress={
              () => { this.props.navigation.navigate("ListScreen"); }
            }
          />
          <CustomButton
            text="Save"
            width="44%"
            onPress={ () => {
              AsyncStorage.getItem("restaurants",
                function(inError, inRestaurants) {
                  if (inRestaurants === null) {
                    inRestaurants = [ ];
                  } else {
                    inRestaurants = JSON.parse(inRestaurants);
                  }
                  inRestaurants.push(this.state);
                  AsyncStorage.setItem("restaurants",
                    JSON.stringify(inRestaurants), function() {
                      this.props.navigation.navigate("ListScreen");
                    }.bind(this)
                  );
                }.bind(this)
              );
            } }
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>

  ); }
}
```

Comment: try to add minimum of codes and format it well

Answer (score 0):

In order to re-render `FlatList`, you must update it's `data` property (`this.state.listData` in your case)

Comment: yes i update data but the data only see when i reload app

Comment: you can share any example

Comment: @MemoFigueredo I can not because my app is not open sourced and code of each screen is quite big. Btw, you have needed line in your code: `this.setState({ listData : inRestaurants });`. You just need to copy it it into `onPress` handler of save button

Comment: this not work for me i save data but the table items not appearance only when y reload app appearance any other idea i use very options to re render but not work i help please

Comment: @MemoFigueredo I'm not sure I understand your problem. Do you mean that you have two pages, one with list and one page that adds item? And new item appears in list only after reload? If that's the case, you need to fetch data using [`useFocusEffect`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/#using-with-class-component) hook of react-navigation instead of `componentDidMount`, because react-navigation does not unmount page components often

Answer (score 0):

this is photos:

[image]

this image save item but no reload flatList automatically
but a i reload app this appearance:

[image]